# How to prevent LaTeX from hyphenating words containing a dash?

Tags: latex, hyphenation

I would like to globally prevent LaTeX from hyphenating 'Objective-C'. I am aware of the \hyphenation command, but I don't see how I can make use of it. If I pass 'Objective-C' to this command, the dash will be treated as a hint to hyphenate the word there.

One solution I found is wrapping Objective-C into an mbox each time I use it. However, the document I am writing contains this name a lot, and wrapping it into an mbox each time is ugly (as is defining a command and using this over and over again in the source code).

Comment: Recommend asking on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why is defining a new command ugly? It's how \LaTeX\ defines itself.

```
\def\ObjectiveC{\mbox{Objective-C}}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess there really is no other way, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\nobreakdash`. That's what LyX produces when I insert a nonbreakingdash and convert it to tex.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [here](http://java.ugent.be/~tdemedts/latex.php), you could define a command like this:

```
 \newcommand\dash{\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt}}
```

and use it like this

```
Consider the $n$\dash dimensional manifold ...
```

Also, you could use the `babel` package and use `"~` as a protected hyphen. I'm not sure if using `babel` is advisable when writing in english, though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! All of that works, but can not be defined globally, like the \mbox solution :(